# Github action to push build folder to a different repo

Tags: git, github, ssh, repository, cicd

I have 2 repos, repo A with source code and repo B that publishes the build folder to the web.

I have an action for this purpose but im getting an error:

```sh
git clone --single-branch --branch main ***github.com/blockcodelabs/B.git /tmp/tmp.NCbLCG<BR>
Cloning into '/tmp/tmp.NCbLCG'...<BR>
remote: Invalid username or password.<BR>
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/blockcodelabs/B.git/'<BR>
```

The action is setup on Repo A, and Repo B has `secret.ACCESS_TOKEN`:

```
name: Push File(or Dir) to another repository

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  copy-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Push to another repo
      uses: dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action@main
      env:
        ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }} 
      with:
        source_file: 'build'
        destination_repo: 'blockcodelabs/B'
        destination_folder: 'build'
        user_email: 'email'
        user_name: 'username'
        commit_message: 'Automatic Build To B'
```

*Update - added picture on error point, for more details.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check at which point in your GitHub action the error occur:

- at the `actions/checkout@v2` step? (in which case, an access token should be used there)
- at the `dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action@main` step

In both instance, the URL used is an HTTPS one, not an SSH one.

The [`dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action` `entrypoint.sh`#L28](https://github.com/dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action/blob/bbebd3da22e4a37d04dca5f782edd5201cb97083/entrypoint.sh#L28) shows:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch $INPUT_DESTINATION_BRANCH \
"https://x-access-token:$API_TOKEN_GITHUB@$INPUT_GIT_SERVER/$INPUT_DESTINATION_REPO.git" "$CLONE_DIR"
```

That means you need to set `API_TOKEN_GITHUB` with your secret, in order for the git clone to succeed.

```yaml
env:
        API_TOKEN_GITHUB: ${{ secrets.API_TOKEN_GITHUB }}
```

That is: `API_TOKEN_GITHUB`, not `ACCESS_TOKEN`.

---

As noted in "[`API_TOKEN_GITHUB` not recognized with `copy_file_to_another_repo_action` GitHub workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75216087/6309)" by [rempsyc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9370662/rempsyc):

> The issue in my case was that I had created the secret in the destination repo instead of the source repo.
> Swapping those two fixed the issue.

So be mindful *where* you have created the secret.

Comment: its happening on the  dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action@main step.

Comment: added a screenshot for better details.

Comment: @LGarcia OK, thank you for the update. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ive updated the variable but still getting the same error. Its a Personal Access Token is that the correct type?

Comment: @LGarcia Check first, through an echo, that `secrets.API_TOKEN_GITHUB` has a value (and the expected one, the `ghp_...`. If so, check the [scope of the token](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps). Maybe a wider scope would help.

Comment: I have the same issue. I've first tried a fine-grained token but it didn't work. Then I tried a classic token and it also didn't work. Have you ever found a solution @LGarcia?

Comment: I have posted my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216087/api-token-github-not-recognized-with-copy-file-to-another-repo-action-github

Comment: @rempsyc I see you have found the root cause, good catch. I have edited the answer to reference your error message and own answer, for more visibility.