# `API_TOKEN_GITHUB` not recognized with `copy_file_to_another_repo_action` GitHub workflow

Tags: git, repository, github-actions, github-secret, github-token

I am using the `copy_file_to_another_repo_action` GitHub workflow from `dmnemec` (https://github.com/dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action) to push a file from one repo that I own to another repo that I own (here is my [workflow](https://github.com/rempsyc/cv/blob/main/.github/workflows/update_cv.yml)).

The workflow succeeds until it tries to push the commit, at which points it fails with message "Invalid username or password":

```
Pushing git commit
+ git push -u origin HEAD:master
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/rempsyc/starter-academic.git/'
```

Yet, I have created a GitHub secret called `API_TOKEN_GITHUB` (like in the workflow file) in the source repo that pushes the file:

[image]

The token has the following permissions:

[image]

I've tried both a fine-grained token and classic token with appropriate permissions, with the same result. Those are the permissions for the fined-grained token (only for the destination repo, where the file needs to be uploaded):

[image]

Because the workflow uses the API_TOKEN_GITHUB with `env:` instead of `with:`, I tried using an environment secret instead, with the same result:

[image]

Is there something obvious I am missing?

This is the same question as: [Github action to push build folder to a different repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819685/github-action-to-push-build-folder-to-a-different-repo). However, it has no accepted answer (and the current answer also hasn't worked for me). There is also [How to commit and push to a private repo(A), from a different repo(B), in github actions workflow (B) , using personal access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70225077/how-to-commit-and-push-to-a-private-repoa-from-a-different-repob-in-github) but I am following the same steps and still facing this issue.

## Edit:

I tested my token as per the troubleshooting steps listed here (https://cpina.github.io/push-to-another-repository-docs/troubleshooting.html) and the token works as expected: I was able to create a branch and push to it.

Note that I forgot to mention that I've changed the destination branch to master from the original workflow (`destination_branch: 'master'`) since the default was main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my case was that I had created the secret in the destination repo instead of the source repo. Swapping those two fixed the issue.